# WPF - Bind between two CheckBoxes' Content with a Label.Content in two different windows

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two windows in my project(MainWindow and one small window for some properties of controls of the MainWindow). In one Tab in the MainWindow there is a Grid divided to ten Columns. In each Column there are some Controls. Below is a sample code of my project.

I want if I check the Period(CheckBox in PropertiesWindow) the Label(MainWindow) to be "Period" and when I check the Frequency(CheckBox in PropertiesWindow) the Label(MainWindow) to be "Frequency".

I want, when I check one of the checkboxes at the  PropertiesWindow (Period or Frequency), the Label (lb_freq1) at the MainWindow to change its Content according to the Content of the checked CheckBox. (Moreover, the selected units to be displayed at the time_div1(Label)).

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

XAML MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-wpf1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="wpf1" Height="720" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="kkk.bmp" Background="#FFE0E0E0" Foreground="#FF49A81D" BorderBrush="#FFB93838" >
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label x:Name="lb_freq1" Content="Period" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txt_freq1" Width="50" Height="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label x:Name="time_div1" Content="us" Width="20" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Label x:Name="lb_width1" Content="Pulse Width" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txt_width1" Width="50" Height="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Label x:Name="pv_div1" Content="us" Width="20" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="Properties1" Content="Properties" Margin="10,30,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" Click="Properties1_Click" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDITED**
Code Behind MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace wpf1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Properties1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string res1 = lb_freq1.Content.ToString();
            string res3 = time_div1.Content.ToString();

            var newWindow = new PWMProperties();
            newWindow.Owner = this;
            newWindow.ShowDialog();

            string result1 = newWindow.Value1;
            if (result1 == null)
            {
                lb_freq1.Content = res1;
            }
            else
            {
                lb_freq1.Content = result1;
            }

            string result3 = newWindow.Unit1;
            if (result3 == null)
            {
                time_div1.Content = res3;
            }
            else
            {
                time_div1.Content = result3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML PropertiesWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf1.PWMProperties"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Properties" Height="335" Width="285" ResizeMode="NoResize" BorderThickness="0" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolConverter2 x:Key="Converter"></local:BoolConverter2>
    <local:BoolConverter x:Key="Reverse"></local:BoolConverter>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,49,0">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="SelectPeriod" Content="Period" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="SelectPeriod_Click" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="PeriodUnits" Padding="3,2,2,2" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="us" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectPeriod, Path=IsChecked}" SelectionChanged="PeriodUnits_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodComboBoxItems}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="SelectFrequency" Content="Frequency" Click="SelectFrequency_Click" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="FrequencyUnits" Padding="3,2,2,2" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Hz" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectFrequency, Path=IsChecked}" SelectionChanged="FrequencyUnits_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyComboBoxItems}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0">
            <Button x:Name="OkButton" Content="OK" Margin="135,5,10,5" Click="OkButton_Click" Width="60" />
            <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="60" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDITED**
Code Behind PropertiesWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace wpf1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Analog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PWMProperties : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> PeriodComboBoxItems { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> FrequencyComboBoxItems { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> PulseWidthComboBoxItems { get; set;}

        public PWMProperties()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.PeriodComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "us", "ms", "s" };
            this.FrequencyComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Hz", "kHz", "MHz" };
            this.PulseWidthComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "us", "ms", "s" };
        }

        string val1, val2, unit1, unit2;

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectPeriod.IsChecked == true)
            {
                val1 = "Period";
                if (unit1 == null || unit1!="ms") unit1 = "us";
            }

            if (SelectFrequency.IsChecked == true)
            {
                val1 = "Frequency";
                if (unit1 == null || unit1!="kHz") unit1 = "Hz";
            }

            DialogResult = true;
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = false;
        }

        public string Value1 { get { return val1; } }

        public string Value2 { get { return val2; } }

        public string Unit1 { get { return unit1; } }

        public string Unit2 { get { return unit2; } }

        private void PeriodUnits_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            unit1 = PeriodUnits.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void FrequencyUnits_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            unit1 = FrequencyUnits.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

    }

    public class BoolConverter2 : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool v = (bool)value;
            return v;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Second possible solution:**

Then, I've added to my MainWindow code a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _value1 = "Period";

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Value1
        {
            get { return _value1; }
            set
            {
                _value1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value1");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

So, most of the code behind of the PropertiesWindow is deleted and I use Binding for the change of lb_freq1(Label) at the MainWindow.

```
<Label x:Name="lb_freq1" Content="{Binding Value1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

I don't know how to continue from that state. I'm new to WPF and C#, and I would be thankful if someone could help me in any way.

**MAIN ISSUE**

I've edited my first solution, so if someone could take a look. What I managed to do now is almost what i want. But, there is a problem. I want, when I click on the OK.Button, the "settings" I made at Properties.Window should change the Labels at MainWindow. Although, when I click on the Cancel.Button or the Close.Button at the upper right corner, any changes made at the Properties.Window should not change the Labels at MainWindow.

Moreover, when I close the Properties.Window, and then open it again for a second time, the CheckBoxes and ComboBox.SelectedItems need to have the same state they had when the Properties.Window closed. But that doesn't happen.

Comment: do you want the properties window to be open and editable at the same time as the main window? As in, do you want access and editing of both windows as the same time? What i am getting at, could the Properties window be a dialog?

Comment: @GingerNinja - I've edited my code and made my question a little bit more specific. Maybe, now, you could give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Chrislo, that still doesnt really answer my question. I  am more so asking about the functionality. because if you can have it that the mainwindow is not accessible while the property window is open, you can use ShowDialog. and then to get the update of data, you can use the DialogResult and the view model. I typically do it for "edit" dialog windows. But it wont work as smooth if you want to use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `DataContext` of the two windows properly. Currently, you are setting and overriding it in multiple places. Here is my suggestions:

Use `ElementName` in your Binding in your windows, i.e., `wpf1.PWMProperties` and `wpf1.MainWindow`, whenever you want to Bind to a property in them. In other words, give them a name and Bind to them. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf1.PWMProperties"
   .....
  Name="owner">
   .....
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,49,0">
                .....
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PeriodComboBoxItems, ElementName=owner}">
            </StackPanel>
```

use DataContext for Binding to `Value1` in your ViewModel. Set the `DataContext` of both Windows to be the instance of your ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Properties1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newWindow = new PWMProperties();
        newWindow.Owner = this;
        newWindow.DataContext = viewModel; 
        newWindow.Show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried a little bit working with the viewModel but didn't manage to have what I want. I've edited my code and made my question a little bit more specific. Maybe, now, you could give me some advice. Thanks in advance.